# Pointer not printing in the desired way

Tags: c, pointers

This is a C code

```
int (*a)[3];
```

`a` is a pointer to an array of 3 integers

```
a=(int (*)[3])malloc(sizeof(int)*3);
```

note the Typecast used here; the number of elements must be specified in the typecast shown. Also, the brackets around the `*` is                                                                           necessary.

```
printf("brrbrrbrr  %d  %d  %d %d\n",&a,a,a+1,a+2);

*(a+0)[0]=40;
*(a+0)[1]=41;
*(a+0)[2]=42;
printf("noobnoob  %d %d %d \n",a[0][0],*(a+0)[1],(*(*(a+0)+2)));
```

The output is:

```
brrbrrbrr  -7077000  29278656  29278668 29278680
noobnoob  40 41 0
```

I am not getting why the last number is 0 instead of 42?

Comment: to print the address, use `%p`

Comment: @LPs no, that's wrong, see Gopi's answer.

Comment: `*(a+0)[1]=41;` <- I don't remember the precedence rules entirely, but if this is parsed as `*((a+0)[1]) = 41;` then that's UB.

Comment: @LPs `a` is a pointer to an array, not a pointer to the first element of the array. Thus, `*a` is the array. Thus, `(*a)[0]` is its first element, `(*a)[1]` is its second element, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexation has higher precedence than dereferencing a pointer. Your assignments don't do what you want. They are evaluated like:

```
*((a+0)[0])=40;
*((a+0)[1])=41;
*((a+0)[2])=42;
```

If you want to keep your syntax, you shall use parenthesis like:

```
(*(a+0))[0] = 40;
(*(a+0))[1] = 41;
(*(a+0))[2] = 42;
```

The same applies for printing the second element of the array. `*(a+0)[1]` shall be `(*(a+0))[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is

```
int (*a)[3] = malloc(sizeof(int) *3);

(*a)[0] = 40;
(*a)[1] = 41;
(*a)[2] = 42;


printf("%d %d %d\n",(*a)[0],(*a)[1],(*a)[2]);
```

a is a pointer to an array of 3 int members. So allocate memory for the pointer and store values as shown above.

If you want the address of where the values are stored then you should do

```
printf("%p\n",(void*)(a)[0]);
```